# Google API OAuth 2: Use authorization code as a string with Google's .NET libraries

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

My WinForms app needs to access one of the Google API's (Calendar). For this, the app needs to have authorization, and Google has provided OAuth 2 for this purpose. I've read everything on their docs site [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).

From another documentation page on Google I learned how to get the authorization key via a browser request. This takes place in a Console C# application. What it does is:

```
var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
var service = new CalendarService(auth);
string id = <calendar id>;
Calendar calendar = service.Calendars.Get(id).Fetch();
```

At the last line, a browser window is opened with a Google page asking me to allow the app access to my Google account. In the console application, a ReadLine() is waiting for input. This comes from the `GetAuthorization` method:

```
private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
{
    // Get the auth URL:
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
    Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

    // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
    Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
    Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
    string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
    return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
}
```

So I grant my app access to my Gmail account, and I get a code in return. This code I paste back into the console window, and the rest of the app does its work as it should (in my case, making a new Calendar event).

But my problem is the fact that I want this functionality in a WinForms app, not a Console app. I have *not* been able to find anything on Google's pages regarding this.

What I have so far:

- User clicks a button, the browser is opened and the user grants access and retrieves the code.
- User pastes this code into the app.
- Another button is clicked, and this is where I would like to use the user-entered code for the authorization process. This is a string, and I don't know how to combine this with all the authentication methods written in the top of this post.

I have a feeling it could be possible with the use of Google's REST client instead of the native .NET libraries, but I sincerely want to use the .NET libraries instead of REST.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [AuthorizationMgr](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/SampleHelper/AuthorizationMgr.cs?repo=samples) class and in particular at RequestNativeAuthorization method. It uses a [LoopbackServerAuthorizationFlow](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/SampleHelper/NativeAuthorizationFlows/LoopbackServerAuthorizationFlow.cs?repo=samples) class, which created a tcp listener for you and get the code from the incoming request.

You should also take a look at one of the samples that uses that mechanism (e.g. [CreateTask](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.CreateTasks/Program.cs?repo=samples) sample)